# Sum and difference formula for $\tan$ - I keep getting positive instead of negative answer

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry if this question is long/repetitive. I'm trying to list every single step to see where I've messed up.

The question is to find $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{3})$. Using a calculator, I get $-3.72$ or $-2 -\sqrt{3}$. This will be used to check my answer.

I know that the sum and difference formula for $\tan$ is:

$$\tan(\alpha \pm \beta) = \frac{\tan(\alpha) \pm \tan(\beta)}{1 \mp \tan(\alpha) \tan(\beta)}$$

Plugging the values in, I get:

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) + \tan(\frac{\pi}{3})}{1 - \tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) \tan(\frac{\pi}{3})}$$

$$\frac{1 + \sqrt3}{1 - (1)(\sqrt3)}$$

$$\frac{1 + \sqrt3}{1 - \sqrt3}$$

Now in order to rationalize this, I must multiply by the conjugate of $\sqrt3 - 1$:

$$\frac{(\sqrt3 + 1)(\sqrt3 + 1)}{(\sqrt3 - 1)(\sqrt3 + 1)}$$

The formulas for easy FOIL is:

$$(x + a)(x + a) = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$$
$$(x + a)(x - a) = x^2 - a^2$$

Resulting in:

$$\frac{3 + 2\sqrt3 + 1}{3 - 1}$$
$$\frac{4 + 2\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$2 + \sqrt3$$

As you can see, the answer is correct, but the signs are incorrect. Where did I screw up?

Comment: before and after the line with "rationalize this" you switched $1 - \sqrt 3$ to $\sqrt 3 - 1$

Answer (score 2):

In the step where you multiplied through by $\sqrt3+1$, you switched $1-\sqrt3$ in the denominator for its negative $\sqrt3-1$.